# Move all SharePoint Databases to new SQL Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sql-server, database-server

SharePoint databases are running in a instance SP16 on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter at the moment. SharePoint is installed with 4 machine MinRole WFE-APP-Search-DC.

We want to get rid of the Windows Server 2012 R2 and want to have SQL Server running on a newer Version of Windows Server. Due to this the complete SQL Server instance or all containing databases have to move to a new server being the new SQL Server.

**Planning to shutdown SharePoint, backup/restore databases to new SQL Server and run config wizard on SharePoint App Server.**

**Any experiences with this? Is this enough or do I have to keep something else in mind?**

Answer (score 0):

getting rid of windows server is a contradictory part here. I am not aware of user user hits but with 1 WFE & a cluster BD or 1 DC(db) you may run your show.
Please clarify basic requirement.